# Latch circuit requiring the button to be pressed 6 times

Tags: switches, switching

I need a low dc voltage circuit that will control a resistive load with a single push button. In order for the load to be powered the push button must be pressed 5 times within 1.5s and then the push button must be held down. Once the the push button is released, it can be pressed again and the load will be powered. Once the button is pressed 5 times within 1.5s again the device will be off and will require the button to be pressed 5 times within 1.5s to allow the load to be powered. 
Due to restriction of space, I need this as small as possible. What is the most space saving way to get this accomplished?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a PIC10F200 in the MC package for the state machine you need. The load current wasn't specified, so that's another matter.

Comment: As @jonk says, use a cheap microcontroller with an internal oscillator. There are plenty on the market. An 8-pin device will do this nicely for under a quid, compiling the software with manufacturer's free development tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to @jonk for this (see above comment). This is just a sketch that illustrates my interpretation of his comment.

While not meant to be ready to wire, it's provides a place to start should you decide to take this approach.

[image]